# python what is the data type of level={s}

Tags: python, data-structures

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeInvalidParentheses(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        def isvalid(s):
            ctr=0
            for string in s:
                if string=='(':
                    ctr+=1
                if string==')':
                    ctr-=1
                    if ctr<0:
                        return False
            return ctr==0
        n=len(s)
        level={s}
        while level:
            valid = filter(isvalid, level)
            if valid:
                return valid
            level = {s[:i] + s[i+1:] for s in level for i in range(n)}
```

I am wondering what the data type of `level` is, because it doesn't look like a dictionary.

Comment: it is an example of a  set

Comment: Did you try calling `type` on it?

Comment: Why bother asking something you could so easily have googled?

Comment: Please don't put `***` in code. SO doesn't highlight it, it just shows it literally, and then it's not valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which is a data structure that only holds unique objects.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is a dictionary.

`set()`, `{x}`, `{x, y}`, `{x, y, z, ...}` are sets.

`{x:y, ...}` (i.e. if it has a colon `:`) are dictionaries.

Comment: Unless it's a dict comprehension (which evaluates to a dictionary).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that has a colon.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't a dictionary.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams in what way is it not a dictionary?

Comment: The compiler uses `STORE_MAP` for a dictionary, but uses a completely different sequence of bytecode for a dict comprehension.